# I will access a list of files that has a prefix. How do I map a particular set of files to a particular external table using PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

Our system will get csv files at regular intervals.Is there a way possible to map those files with decided prefixes to external tables using PL/SQL?

Comment: if this is your question, the answer is Yes.

Comment: An external table points to a single file. We have a file that gets replaced everyday, so the name doesn't change. If you want to open different files, your solution will rely on either UTL_FILE, or you will need some code (I have an old java library I use) to search the directory and load the files.

Comment: @BrianLeach A few corrections. 1. An external table can reference multiple files, not just one. 2. You can easily change the files reference by an external table using ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE and modifying the LOCATION parameter.